# How to start a command upon login in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, login, xkb

I would like to run `xkbcomp` upon a user login in order to modify its keyboard. The command works fine from a terminal after login. The system is an unmodified Fedora 20 Desktop Edition.

I tried to add the command (with full paths) to

- `gnome-session-properties`
- `$HOME/.xinitrc`

I also added an additional entry to `/etc/xdg/autostart/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Programmers on AZERTY
Exec=/usr/bin/xkbcomp /home/w/azerty_prog.xkb $DISPLAY
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

None of these work, the keyboard is not modified (I do not know where logs are located). Where should I add this entry?

Comment: `.xinitrc` is only executed when you run `startx` to start X. Are you sure that your script isn't executed? Or could it be that your script runs, but Gnome's keyboard configuration is loaded later and overrides your settings?

Comment: @Gilles: I do not know whether my script runs or not (I did not find any startup logs). It could be very well that, as you mention, it runs too early in the startup process. I do not know much about GNOME so I would be glad to move it to the right place so that it starts late (together with other applications, this is what I expected from `gnome-session-properties`)

Comment: Put your settings in a script, change the desktop entry to `Exec=/path/to/my/script`, and add a logging line like `date >>~/myscript.log` to the script.

Comment: Good idea, I did it and I see that the script is indeed launched. I checked for the error code of the `xkbcomp`entry and it is `0` (so the call is successful). Since all basing GNOME startup is done at this point, I have no idea what could reset the settings pushed by the command above (there is nothing special in `gnome-session-properties`)

Comment: @WoJ - you'll have to add a short timeout before running the command, e.g. `sleep 5 && /usr/bin/xkbcomp /home/w/azerty_prog.xkb $DISPLAY`. I put it in a script & loaded it via `gnome-session-properties`, works fine.